# jQuery - toggle background color on divs using animate Still Needs Help 19.02.2012

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I wish to avoid using css transitions.

I have three divs of the same class. I'm attempting to toggle the background color of one div when clicked. When the div is clicked again, or one of the other are clicked, I wish it to return to default.

I have included the jQuery color plugin and succeded in changing the color on click. I belive that my conditions are wrong and thats why i cant change the color back when clicking the other div.

This is what i've done:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.link').click(function() {
        var $me = $(this);
        if ($me.css("background-color") == "#993") {
            $me.animate({backgroundColor:"#246"}, 500);
        } else {
            $(".link").each(function() {
                if ($(this) != $me) {
                    if ($(this).css("background-color") == "#246") {
                        $(this).animate({backgroundColor:"#993"}, 500);
                    }
                } 
            });
            $me.animate({backgroundColor:"#246"}, 500);
        }
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.link {
    width:100px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#993;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="link">link</div>
    <div class="link">link2</div>
    <div class="link">link3</div>
```

I have had some trouble understanding the backgroundColor consept and hope for help. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function animateBackgroundColor() {
    $('.foo').toggleClass('fooAct');
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.foo').click(function (){
        animateBackgroundColor();
    });
});
</script>
<style>
div {
height:200px;
}
.foo {
transition: background-color 2s;
-moz-transition: background-color 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: background-color 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: background-color 2s; /* Opera */
background-color: red;
}
.fooAct {
background-color:blue;
}
</style>
<div class="foo"></div>
```

Try this. CSS3 could help if you want to use css as well.

There are 3 divs and when you click one of them, it will become blue. When you click other divs, blue is gonna red and clicked one is gonna blue. If you gonna click blue, It will become blue back.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function animateBackgroundColor(obj) {
    $(obj).toggleClass('fooAct');
    $('.fooAct').not(obj).removeClass('fooAct');

}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.foo').click(function (){
        animateBackgroundColor(this);
    });
});
</script>
<style>
div {
height:100px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
.foo {
transition: background-color 1s;
-moz-transition: background-color 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: background-color 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: background-color 1s; /* Opera */
background-color: red;
}
.fooAct {
background-color:blue;
}
</style>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
```

Comment: I like this fade, but the problem isn't really to change the color of a div back and forth, but to get the clicked div to change color when clicking another div of the same class. Thanks for the input. :)

Comment: Now we're talking. This looks great. I'll have to experiment a little, but I think this just might be it. Will this work in ie? I guess ie sorts under the first css line "transition:"

Comment: all browsers except ie working great. need css3 support for transation. :/

Comment: ah,I was afraid of that. I'll just hope that ie10 supports it and that people are quick to upgrade. :)

Answer (score 3):

`background-color` cannot be animated by default with jQuery. You need to use a plugin such as [jQuery Color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) which is part of the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/).

Then you can just do it with `toggle()`:

**html**

```
<div></div>
<button>Color</button>
```

**css**

```
div { 
    height: 50px; 
    width: 50px; 
    background: #ff0000; 
}
```

**jQ**

```
$('button').toggle(function(){
    $('div').animate({'background-color': '#00ff00'});
}, function(){
    $('div').animate({'background-color': '#ff0000'});
});
```

**example**
http://jsfiddle.net/kh6pj/1/

Comment: Yes, i got that far. I have the plug in included and should have mentioned it. I have managed it to animate color on click, but failed to animate it back on clicking the other div. I guess my conditions are wrong.

Comment: ok. Thanks for the input, but the problem isn't changing or animating the color of a div. The problem is to change the color of one of several identical divs and make shure it changes back when i click one of the other divs.